# Use a Collectionviewcontroller on a view inside main view

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my IPad Application I have a main view and it contains `three child views`

1. top
2. middle
3. and bottom

Is it possible to use different view controller on different child views?
For Example i want to use collection view controller on the bottom view and top view.
if yes then is it possible to add and delete cells dynamicially?
 A small example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Use a collection View Controller on a view first you have to create a UICollectionViewController with its CollectionView somewhere else. you can create this CollectionViewController in interface builder or programatically. then treat the collectionView of the UICollectionViewController as normal View and add it to your View with desired frame.
If you are not familiar with CollectionView then take a look at some Tutorial on UICollectionView on Google
[UICollectionView tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523238/uicollectionview-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iOS 6 you can create a container view controller easily in a storyboard by dropping ContainerView from the object library.

[image]

Otherwise you will need to implement a container view controller manually. See the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html).